# Toggle div display in search bar

Tags: javascript, html, display

I'm trying to toggle a div display property using a search input. So far everything is working, however, when the search bar is empty, I want it to toggle back to display:none. I can't seem to get it to work, and do not want to use a button to achieve this. Is there a way to fire a function when the input becomes empty? Right now, the function is firing when the page loads, so my divs are starting out hidden. I'd like them to display when a their relative tag is input into the search bar, but to hide again when the input is empty or their exact tag is not in the input. Any help would be great!
Code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var input = document.getElementById("Search");
  var filter = input.value.toLowerCase();
  var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('connect-cat');


      for (i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {

      if (nodes[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(filter)) {
          nodes[i].style.display = "block";
        } else {
          nodes[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }

    };

function check()
{
  var isEmpty = $('Search').is(":empty");
  $('#silent').toggle(isEmpty);

};
```

Input bar:

```
<input type="text" id="Search" onKeyup="myFunction();" Placeholder="Please enter a search term...">
```

The check function is firing at the top of the page:

```
  $(document).ready(function()
{ 
  check();  
}
```

Comment: You forgot the id hash `$(“#Search”)`

Answer (score 0):

You should attach the event on the input field instead.

Try something like this:

```
$('#Search').change(function() {
    var length = $(this).val().length;
    if (length == 0) {
        // hide div
    }
});
```